# Problems while applying multiple conditions to validate an array?

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am receiving a number of arrays like this:

```
arr1 = np.asarray([41, 183, 101, 1607, 70, 137])

arr2 = np.asarray([300, 250, 300, 17, 300, 190])

arr3 = np.asarray([41, 10, 60, 1207, 70, 137])
```

Which I am validating with this function:

```
def check(arr):
    if arr[ arr >= 90 ].size >= 4:
        return 'maybe'
    elif arr[ arr >= 250 ].size >= 4:
        return 'yes'
    elif arr[ arr < 90 ].size >= 4:
        return 'no'
```

The condition that I would like to apply is, if at least 4 elements of the array are greater than 90, return `"maybe"`, at the same time if at least 4 elements are greater than 250 the array should be `"yes"`. Finally, if less than 4 elements are greater than 90, I should return `"no"`.

I tried to apply the above function and even `np.where`. Nevertheless, the function is not working for arr2, as it is returning `maybe` instead of `yes`. What is the correct and pythonic (one-liner) way of checking multiple conditions over these arrays?

Comment: Any number > 250 is also > 90; you have no way to reach your "yes" branch.  Rearrange your conditions from most restrictive to least restrictive.

Comment: I know that one condition is  not reachable. That's why I am asking if there is a better way to apply all those conditionals @Prune

Comment: Also, the question is reproductible and is following the rules of the community.

Comment: Since the given way doesn't work ... yes, there's a better way.  As I said, rearrange the conditions.  Also, your final clause can be a simple `else` rather than a superfluous check.

Comment: Yes, this *can* be done in one line: use a nested ternary operator.  However, I think that it's more readable in the format you've already chosen.

Comment: How does a solution with the ternary operator looks liket? Does using this operator allow me to multicheck n conditions? @Prune

Comment: These are questions you can answer from the existing documentation.

Comment: numpy documentation or what documentation? @Prune

Comment: "ternary operator"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner:

```
def check(arr):
    return ['yes', 'maybe', 'no'][np.bincount(np.digitize(arr, [np.inf, 250, 90, -np.inf])).argmax()-1]
```

Comment: could you explain the reasoning. I was planning to use digitalize but I did not know how

Comment: The elements in ```arr``` will be compared with consecutive pairs in ```bins```. The first bin is between ```np.inf``` and ```250```, the second is between ```250``` and ```90```, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Once a condition evaluates to True the rest of the conditions are no longer evaluated. You need to switch the order of the first two conditions.

A one-liner would look as follows:

```py
def check(arr):
    return 'yes' if arr[ arr >= 250 ].size >= 4 else 'maybe' if arr[ arr >= 90 ].size >= 4 else 'no'
```

Though, Fitting everything on one line would violate PEP-8 where it is mandated that lines should not exceed 80 characters in length, hence being unpythonic.

Comment: yes that's the problem with this solution, is there any operatror that allow me multi check several conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as it's written. You're checking for the "maybe" condition first, and `arr2` fits the condition: any element >250 is also >90.
If possible, rearrange your conditions to be mutually exclusive to avoid these sort of issues.
If your conditions are not supposed to be mutually exclusive, then you have 2 fixes: 1) if you want `arr2`, which is both "yes" and "maybe", to return "yes", then test the "yes" condition before the "maybe" condition. 2) test every condition and collect the results. I like 2, so this is what it looks like:

```
def ismaybe(arr): return arr[ arr >= 90 ].size >= 4
def isyes(arr): return arr[ arr >= 250 ].size >= 4
def isno(arr): return arr[ arr < 90 ].size >= 4
def check(arr): return {"maybe": ismaybe(arr), "yes": isyes(arr), "no":, isno(arr)}
```

Comment: Is there a one liner solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Like a list comprehention or a similar operator like `where` for multiple conditions

Comment: Putting multiple condition checks into one line is doable with Python's one-line if-else syntax. But that's not what's tripping you up right now. Your conditions are not mutually exclusive; in other words, multiple conditions can be true for your array. `arr2` satisfied both "maybe" and "yes". Since you tested for "maybe" first, the if-statement returns "maybe".
If you are open to returning *multiple* condition checks, I could amend my answer to show you something like that.

Comment: That would work, I am just curious for a one line solution